# No speed benefit with Prepared Statements?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'd heard Prepared Statements with a MySQL database can offer speed increases if the query is being done multiple times, and I thought I had an ideal case for that in a project. But I ran some benchmarks and found the exact opposite. Am I using these statements wrong (not an ideal situation for Prepared Statements), or are they just not as fast as I thought they were?

The situation is a tournament result grid. There's multiple schools entered in multiple events, and each school has a score for each event. In order to get an individual school's scores for all events, it takes a SQL query with a LEFT JOIN like:

```
SELECT e.`id`, e.`name`, c.`competing`, c.`raw`, c.`final` FROM `events` e LEFT JOIN `scores` c ON e.`id`=c.`event_id` WHERE c.`school_id`=:school_id;
```

I wrote two PHP test scripts to run against sample data (200 events), using the native PDO objects (`prepare()`/`bindValue()`/`execute()` versus `query()`):

**EDIT** Modified tests with below suggestions (vanilla query needs a fetch, fetch different IDs, and bind the prepare outside the loop). Only gives a modest speed advantage to prepared statements now:

**Prepared Statement:**

```
$start = microtime(true);
$sql = 'SELECT e.`id`, e.`name`, c.`competing`, c.`raw`, c.`final` FROM `events` e LEFT JOIN `scores` c ON e.`id`=c.`event_id` WHERE c.`school_id`=:school_id';
echo $sql."<br />\n";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$sid = 0;
$stmt->bindParam(':school_id', $sid);
for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
    $sid = rand(1,499);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rs = $stmt->fetchAll();
}
$delta = bcsub(microtime(true), $start, 4);
echo "<strong>Overall time:</strong> $delta<br />\n";
echo "<strong>Average time:</strong> ".($delta/$max)."<br />\n";
```

**Vanilla Query:**

```
set_time_limit(15); // Add time for each run
$start = microtime(true);
$sql = 'SELECT e.`id`, e.`name`, c.`competing`, c.`raw`, c.`final` FROM `events` e LEFT JOIN `scores` c ON e.`id`=c.`event_id` WHERE c.`school_id`={$sid}';
echo $sql."<br />\n";
for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
    $sid = rand(1,499);
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT e.`id`, e.`name`, c.`competing`, c.`raw`, c.`final` FROM `events` e LEFT JOIN `scores` c ON e.`id`=c.`event_id` WHERE c.`school_id`={$sid}");
    $rs = $stmt->fetchAll();
}
$delta = bcsub(microtime(true), $start, 4);
echo "<strong>Overall time:</strong> $delta<br />\n";
echo "<strong>Average time:</strong> ".($delta/$max)."<br />\n";
```

I am fetching the same school's event scores (School ID# 10) over and over again, and setting `$max` to 10,000, I get results that show the vanilla queries being 30% faster (25.72 seconds versus 36.79). Am I doing it wrong, or is this accurate that Prepared Statements aren't faster even in a repeating situation?

**EDIT** the updated tests now get 33.95 seconds prepared versus 34.10 vanilla. Huzzah, the prepared statements are faster. But only by a fraction of a second for 10,000 iterations. Possibly because my query is not that complex (Prepared statements cache the parse tree for their advantage)? Or is there more optimizing to do here yet?

Comment: How about comparing with stored procedures? Are you making sure that you have the appropriate indexes?

Comment: I'm not familiar with "stored" procedures; I'll have to look that one up. The `scores` and `events` tables have appropriate indexes (`events` has an `id` field that's PRIMARY, and `scores` as a two-column PRIMARY index on `school_id`/`event_id`)

Comment: "Stored Procedures" are Good.  "Prepared Statements", on the other hand, are just another tool.  They incur some overhead ... but under the right circumstances, they can also yield performance games, increase security and simplify code.  Here's a good link:  http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/?p=187#procon

Comment: @paulsm4 - Most businesses the database is their chief asset. I use stored procedures a lot to ensure security, maintain the business logic and also to ensure performance. You can easily just go through all the procedures to ensure that they are optimized and removed the necessity to double check the programmers code. Just get the web app to only be granted access to those procedures and nothing else.

Comment: @paulsm4 that first "pro" is what I thought I was testing; the caching of the parse tree. The statement being tested has a JOIN in it, which makes it more complex than a simple SELECT, though it could be lots more complex. Is it just that this statement isn't complex enough to show the benefits of parse tree caching?

Comment: The lack of complexity may be an issue.  You should be able to get a quite precise time for the query from the mysql database (through the command line or a tool like PHPMyAdmin) and determine how much time is actual query time versus method call overhead.
You may see improvements on more complex queries that require more optimization time, or are passing more parameters (since only the parameter values are sent on each execute())

Comment: @Ed Heal - we're in agreement, correct?  Stored Procedures are "Good".  You can and should use stored procedures whenever/wherever possible.  Correct?

Comment: @paulsm4 - Yes - Stop arbitrary expressions in PHP code. Keep the database secure and *tight*. You can ensure a lot by doing this - security, performance, integrity, even ensuring that the data going in is correct (regular expressions etc). Also you have the added benefit if you want to access the data via another system you can do no need to perform duplicate coding for verification and validation.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It appears that you may not be comparing apples to apples.

[`PDO::query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) Executes an SQL statement, returning a result set as a `PDOStatement` object.

To get the actual results, you need to iterate over the returned object or, as with the prepared statement, call `fetchAll()` to load the entire result set into an array

The correct vanilla query loop should likely then be:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
    $stmt = $db->query($sql);
    $rs = $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

or alternatively removing the `fetchAll()` call from the prepared statement loop.

You could also reduce the method calls required for the prepared statement by using `bindParam()` instead of `bindValue()`

```
$school_id = null;
$stmt->bindParam(':school_id', $school_id);
for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
    $school_id = 10;
    $stmt->execute();
    $rs = $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: Good points! Moving the bind outside the loop sped up the prepared statements a bit, and adding the fetch to the vanilla slowed them down. Now I get 33.95 seconds prepared versus 34.10 vanilla. Huzzah, the prepared statements are faster. But only by a fraction of a second for 10,000 iterations. Possibly because my query is not that complex?

Comment: You will most likely see bigger differences for more complex queries. It appears that you have a single join using a primary key, which really isn't hard for the database to evaluate.  More joins, larger data sets, and multiple indexes to choose between will result in more overhead in creating the execution plan.

Comment: As well, you have a fairly short query with only one variable.  Prepared statements allow only the parameters to be sent to the database on each call to execute(), which will have a greater advantage for longer queries with more variables.

Comment: PDO emulates prepared statements with MySQL by default. That's why there's no noticeable speedup. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

The vanilla query is executing the exact same query each time, so you're just testing the "fetch results from query cache" times, not actual query execution time. This isn't a valid test.

You'd have to do the query building INSIDE the loop, so you're forcing a NEW query each time:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
    $sql = <<<EOL
SELECT e.id, e.name, c.competing, c.raw, c.final
FROM events e
LEFT JOIN scores c ON e.id=c.event_id
WHERE c.school_id= $i;
EOL;
    $rs = $db->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: In the Prepared Statement the same value is being bound each time. Are you saying that even when the same value is being bound there's no caching?

Comment: Binding is not a 'free' operation, it's just slightly cheaper than parsing the entire query over and over.

Comment: Um ok, but that's not what I thought I was asking. I had inferred from your first sentence that the *data* was coming from cache in the Vanilla and not in the prepared statement. But I guess I misunderstood.

Comment: That sounds promising, but I tried modifying my tests to pull a random school on each loop execution, and I still see vanilla queries as significantly faster. There's 500 schools in the test data, so 10,000 loops means there will be lots of repeats, but how big is the query cache? Is it possible the server will cache all 500 result sets?

Comment: -1 This isn't the right answer. PDO emulates prepared statements with MySQL by default. That's why there's no noticeable speedup.

Answer (score 2):

None of these people pointed out the patently obviously:

PDO *emulates* prepared statements with MySQL *by default*, even if the driver supports them.

This is the **exact opposite** of what the [PHP PDO manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) says, however, but [**view the source code and you'll see they always, de facto, use emulated prepared statements**](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_driver.c#590) (I thought it was a coding bug, but when I filed a report it was classified as WONT_FIX and I had some Zend dev merely state, "It is our policy to always emulate, just cuz." Which doesn't make sense to me, but o well.

---

To use truly prepared statements, you have to jump through a hoop.  If you don't like this, blame the Zend devs, as the fix looks like it'd take all of 5 minutes (just move the if around).

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, array(ATTR::PDO_EMULATE_PREPARES => false));
```

I'd greatly appreciate it if you'd make this change, rerun your benchmark, and update us as to the timings with this code.

Comment: "It is our policy to always emulate, just cuz". 1. No it is not "just cuz". 2. Some people are working towards enabling "real" prepared statements by default.

Comment: Why would you blame "zend devs" for this?